# Excel VBA - choose workbook to copy from and paste into existing workbook on next blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and have been using the site to piece together a solution.

I need to write a macro that prompts the user to open a file (wb2), copy a row of data from a Sheet1 in that workbook (wb2) and then paste it into the next empty row within the original workbook (wb) also on Sheet1. I got it to work up until I tried adding the code for pasting in the next empty row - I am now receiving the following error message, "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

'Set selectedworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

wb2.Range("A3:E3").Select
Selection.Copy
wb.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

wb2.Close

'Set targetworkbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick note on the subject:
Instead of

```
wb2.Worksheets("Output").Range("J3:R3").Select
Selection.Copy
```

try

```
wb2.Worksheets("Output").Range("J3:R3").Copy
```

Also
Instead of

```
wb.Worksheets("Master").Range("C" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

try

```
wb.Worksheets("Master").Range("C" & LastCellRowNumber).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Often times, `Select` creates unexplainable errors. Particularly when working with multiple workbooks, try to stay away from `Select`. This code comes almost directly from working code I have. Let us know if this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I re-worked the code and got it working. It's probably not the cleanest way to do it, but given my timeline and lack of VBA knowledge, it will have to do.

Many thanks to engineersmnky for their help.

Description: This code should be put into the worksheet you want to paste content into from another workbook. When it runs it will prompt you to open a workbook to copy from ("Output" worksheet), it will then select the cells you specify in the code (JR:R3), paste them in starting at the next empty row of your initial workbook (finding the last row in column C in the "Master" worksheet), and then it will close & save the workbook you just copied from.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Last cell in column
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Master")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
End With

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

'Set selectedworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Select cells to copy
wb2.Worksheets("Output").Range("J3:R3").Select
Selection.Copy

'Go back to original workbook you want to paste into
wb.Activate

'Paste starting at the last empty row
wb.Worksheets("Master").Range("C" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Close and save the workbook you copied from
wb2.Save
wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
Selection.Copy
wb.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just tried your update, but I'm still receiving the same error, "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: try the chain 1 at a time to see where the error occurs because it could be wb does not support `.Cells` since this is a worksheet method.

Comment: Good idea. I went through it like you suggested and the error does occur when it hits the '.Cells' piece.

Comment: so just change the reference and it should be good something like `wb.Worksheets("WORKSHEETNAME").Cells`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I made the update and also removed `wb2.Close` and `Set wb = activeworkbook` and I no longer receive an error message, but I it also doesn't paste anything into my initial worksheet (wb). Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. I can also re-post the code if needed.

Comment: updating your code is always recommended. I think you may need to set an actual worksheet for the copy to function as expected.